# check whether a subroutine exists in a library file

Tags: static-libraries

I am compiling and the error message is

" undefined reference to `pm3warn_'"

so how can I check whether the library file libioapi.a has the subroutine named m3warn? thanks,

Answer (score 1):

use [nm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_(Unix))
e.g

```
$ nm  libioapi.a | grep pm3warn_
```